# trying to create a linear search using a for loop but not entirely sure how?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list = ["Football","Cricket","Rugby","Tennis","Badminton"]

def linearSearch(data,list):

    for i in range(len(list)):

        if data[i] == len[i]:

            return i

linearSearch("Tennis", list)
```

ok so I tried running my code however it says built in function cannot get item
i'm fairly new to programming so i'm unsure what i've done wrong and how to fix it

Comment: Posting a block of code is not a question. You need to ask a specific question and detail what is going wrong, what you've tried, what you expect to happen, and copy and paste any relevant error messages.

Comment: `data[i]`? `data` is the string `Tennis`, not an array...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple:

```
def linearSearch(data,list):
    return list.index(data) if data in list else -1
```

Or if you want to use `for` cycle:

```
def linearSearch(data,list):
    for index, item in enumerate(list):
        if item == data:
            return index
    return -1
```

Comment: list = ["Football","Cricket","Rugby","Tennis","Badminton"]
def linearSearch(data,list):
    if data in list:
        return list.index("Tennis")
    else:
        return -1
like this??

Comment: is there any way it can be done using a for loop, as I've been trying using a for loop to get more advanced in python

Comment: I've added variant with `for` cycle.